# FATAL EXCEPTION: main For input string: "5862.270"

Tags: java, android, currency-formatting

I am trying to format a decimal number as a currency and I have tried probably all methods but for some reason I keep getting `FATAL EXCEPTION: mainjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5862.270"` any solutions?

```
Integer num = Integer.parseInt(parkingList.get(parkingList.size() - 2).getTotalValue());
DecimalFormat svSE = new DecimalFormat("#,###.000");
String result = svSE.format(num);
//format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);

viewHolder.totalbyday.setText(result);
```

My code is inside an adapter as well if that changes anything!

I also tried removing `Integer.parseInt(parkingList.get(parkingList.size() - 2).getTotalValue());` and just putting the number `5862.270` and Istill get the same exception

Comment: you can't have a number with a decimal point as Integer. try float or double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are trying to parse a decimal point number into an Integer.

Change:

```
Integer num = Integer.parseInt(parkingList.get(parkingList.size() - 2).getTotalValue());
```

to:

```
Double num = Double.parseDouble(parkingList.get(parkingList.size() - 2).getTotalValue());
// or
Float num = Float.parseFloat(parkingList.get(parkingList.size() - 2).getTotalValue());
```